# Debugging C++ Abstract Class Implementation

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I have got a problem with the implementation of my abstract classes. The general structure of my library is as follows. I have written abstract interface class like

```
struct IInstrument
{
    virtual double tst(int i) const = 0;
};
```

Its concrete implementation looks like

```
struct subInstrument:IInstrument
{
        virtual double tst(int i) const override {
            const double x = 0.0;
            const double y = 1.0;
            double res = x + y+i;
            return res;
        }
};
```

The third struct in which the tst routine is actually called looks like

```
struct model:AbstractModel{
    virtual double GetNumber(IInstrument const& Bond) const override
    {
        double number = Bond.tst(12);
        return number;
    }
};
```

where AbstractModel is just - as the name says - an abstract mother class of the model class. The thing is that I have a lot of different subinstruments and that is why I don't want to call subinstrument directly in the model class routine getNumber(***).

The code compiles fine in Visual Studio 2015, but the debugging is somehow misbehaving. As I run step by step debugging through my tst routine, the variables x as well as y are ignored. The only variable which definitely has a value is i and res is in the end returned with zero. 
I am not sure about the point which is wrong. Does anyone of you has an idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Make sure you bild in "debug" mode, i.e. without any optimisations.

Comment: Not necessarily related: I'd add a virtual destructor to `IInstrument`.

Comment: `GetNumber` lacks a `return` statement. All bets are off.

Comment: you were right, but the problem seems to be in the tst routine.

Comment: Works fine for me with the return statement in place. If you can't see the variables it's probably because they are local constant values. The compiler can throw them out and build the values right into `double res = 1 + 0+i;`

Comment: For example: https://godbolt.org/g/2UeWu7